# How can I use UTF-8 with Node Express and MSSQL? Cyrillic is not working

Tags: sql-server, node.js, encoding, utf-8

This is what I get when I query the database using [npm-mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql)

```
{
    "product": "123456",
    "name": "ÔÎÒÎÊÎÏÈÐÍÀ ÕÀÐÒÈ£À À6 500 - 10ÃÐ",
    "group": "5",
    "category": "Õàðòè¼à Ôîòîêîïè"
}
```

I can't seem to find a solution to this. The only thing I found is using 'SET NAMES UTF8', but it says it's bad practice?

How do I fix the characters?

Comment: SQL Server does not support utf-8, its unicode support is using UCS-2

Comment: and here you can upvote the request to support utf-8 in sql server: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/362867/add-support-for-storing-utf-8-natively-in-sql-server

Comment: @sepupic Thanks! Didn't know that. Do you know how I could fix that in Node?

Comment: I don't know what this Node Express is but I think you need to convert from UCS-2 to UTF-8, and not on the sever side

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of querying like this:

```
SELECT name 
FROM product
```

It should be like this:

```
SELECT CAST(name as nvarchar(255)) 
FROM product
```